# styling inconsistencies(?) on reload (nextjs project)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have been playing around with next/material-ui and this one issue seems to be baffling me. I have created a small example that reproduces the issue. I am trying to center an element using the Box component of Material-UI. The first time I open the page localhost:3000, it looks nicely centered as I would expect. But when I refresh, the p element seems to go to the top left corner and stays there until I restart the server again.

To top it, the dev and prod modes work differently too:

dev mode (npm run dev): It always behaves as described above

prod mode (npm run build; npm run start): It behaves as described above as long as I have the getInitialProps() function defined. If I comment it out, it works fine.

I don't see any error messages either. What am I missing here?

UPDATE: I switched to using MUI's grid container/items for my layout needs (instead of Box) and now it works as expected. Is that a bug with Box component then? or my misunderstanding of its usage?

My pages/index.js is as below:

```
import React from 'react'
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box'

class Index extends React.Component {

  static async getInitialProps() {
    return { data: "some-data" }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" width="100%" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" mt={10}>
          <p> This is my test </p>
        </Box>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Index
```

Comment: Can you confirm this behavior: run your development more, open the page where the problem is, if the problem occurs, do a hard refresh `Ctrl + R` from your keyboard, did the hard refresh change the behavior?

Comment: @SultanH. I updated my experiment description to answer your question

Comment: @hucqym do you have a `_document.js` file that you could append to the question? specifically looking for your `static getInitalProps(){}`

Comment: @Bryan here is the [_document.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gmRvsF_2N_qVYzCker8YpXG4WCAUalBu)